# Edit page : button redirecting to post grid

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add a button next to the "Update/Publish" button in Wordpress admin edit post page.

[image: Wordpress Post edit page]

The button would be a duplicate of "Update/Publish" but with a redirect to the post grid page.

The view file of the mentioned button is located in wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php:

```
<div id="publishing-action">
<span class="spinner"></span>
<?php
if ( !in_array( $post->post_status, array('publish', 'future', 'private') ) || 0 == $post->ID ) {
    if ( $can_publish ) :
        if ( !empty($post->post_date_gmt) && time() < strtotime( $post->post_date_gmt . ' +0000' ) ) : ?>
        <input name="original_publish" type="hidden" id="original_publish" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Schedule') ?>" />
        <?php submit_button( __( 'Schedule' ), 'primary button-large', 'publish', false ); ?>
<?php   else : ?>
        <input name="original_publish" type="hidden" id="original_publish" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Publish') ?>" />
        <?php submit_button( __( 'Publish' ), 'primary button-large', 'publish', false ); ?>
<?php   endif;
    else : ?>
        <input name="original_publish" type="hidden" id="original_publish" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Submit for Review') ?>" />
        <?php submit_button( __( 'Submit for Review' ), 'primary button-large', 'publish', false ); ?>
<?php
    endif;
} else { ?>
        <input name="original_publish" type="hidden" id="original_publish" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Update') ?>" />
        <input name="save" type="submit" class="button button-primary button-large" id="publish" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update' ) ?>" />
<?php
} ?>
</div>
```